# Spring Security Active Directory bad credentials handling (error 49)

Tags: spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, active-directory, wildfly-8

I have problem with Active Directory authentication in simple Spring web application. I'm using `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` and it seems to work fine for empty login fields and correct credentials. The problem is with invalid credentials (wrong login/pass or both). The application throws exception (error 500) to browser:

```
Error processing request
Context Path: /MYAPPNAME
Servlet Path: /login_check
Path Info: null
Query String: null
Stack Trace:
org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.MYAPPNAME.war:main" from Service Module Loader [Root exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, vece]] (...)
```

**The console root error is:**

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308:
LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, vece]
```

If the credentials are incorrect, shouldn't Spring send user to authentication-failure-url? I don't have any "manager" account to use for ldap BIND, I believe `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` is supposed to bind using credentials from login form. Spring documentation doesn't have anything about binding to AD.

It can probably be solved using custom authentication provider, but I was hoping there is an out-of-the-box solution. There are some similar questions, but none of them very precise or with any useful answer.

How to approach this error?

Is there a way to configure it in XML? Perhaps, to tell AD provider to tread binding error as failed login attempt?

Is custom authentication provider the only solution?

---

**spring-security.xml**

```
<bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
    <property name="rolePrefix" value="" />
</bean> 
<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <constructor-arg name="decisionVoters" ref="roleVoter" />
</bean>
<s:http authentication-manager-ref="ldap-auth" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" use-expressions="false">
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/list**" access="ADGROUP-XYZ" />
    <s:form-login 
        login-page="/login"             
        login-processing-url="/login_check"
        username-parameter="username" 
        password-parameter="password"     
        default-target-url="/list"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?fail" />
    <s:logout 
        invalidate-session="true" 
        logout-success-url="/login?logout" 
        logout-url="/logout"
        delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    <s:csrf />
</s:http>    

<s:authentication-manager id="ldap-auth">
    <s:authentication-provider ref="adAuthenticationProvider" />
</s:authentication-manager> 

<bean id="adAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg value="company.local" />
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://server.company.local:389/" />
    <property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true"/>
    <property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

---

**EDIT**: One ugly fix is to override `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` and change `throw LdapUtils.convertLdapException(e);` to `throw badCredentials(e);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a issue with JBoss EAP initial context.This has been fixed in the latest wildfly versions.check the below links

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2754

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4149

Comment: you can try the sample code  given in the url  https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2754 to fix this issue